# 「リエゾン」に、さらなる意味が？

Tags: translation

以下のところで、「リエゾン」の妙な使い方を見つけました。

> 「なんかってけっかる！」
>
> と叫んだ。これは、なに吐{ぬ}かしてけっかるというべきところを、昂奮{こうふん}したために撥音便{はつおんびん}やらリエゾンやらが一度に作用してしまったのである。彼はもう一度くりかえした。
>
> 「なんかってけっかる！」

ーー「日本三文オペラ」、１９２頁

複数の辞書を引いても、"liaison"の定義しか出ません。が、明らかに、そういった意味で使われていません。とすると、どういうことを指しているのですか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

リエゾン = 音と音のつながり.
Liaison is a term in phonetics describing a phenomenon when multiple sounds get linked together.

Example usage  (from http://www.liaisonbox.com/archives/2005/09/post_16.html):

> 「しっとリッチ」、別項で取り上げた「こんがりっち製法」と同じ作りですね。この「『り』で終わる形容詞＋リッチ」というリエゾンの特徴を考えると、
>
> - 「り」の２文字前には促音便「っ」とか撥音便「ん」が来ることが多い。「○っ○リッチ」「○ん○リッチ」
> - 音が「タッカタッカ」とスキップしているようで非常にリズムがいい。
> - カタカナの「リ」とひらがなの「り」がよく似てるので見た目もつながりがいい。
>
> といったものがあげられます。

Comment: What is this 「形容詞 + リッチ」 all about?

Comment: Ah, I see, you just copy & pasted from here: http://www.liaisonbox.com/archives/2005/09/post_16.html  without citing the source.  That is called "plagia..."

Comment: I think it would have been plagiarism if I claimed that particular sentence was mine, which I didn't. Pasted URL to the source.

Comment: Please see [How to reference materials written by others](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) ([日本語訳](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)).  You are required to cite sources when quoting, supplying a link if applicable.

Comment: @DmitryAleks You might include the whole phrase. The example is a little bit hard to understand as it is now without clicking through.

Comment: @bright-star Done.

Comment: 念のため: http://www.liaisonbox.com/about 『この「日本語リエゾン」というカテゴリ分けは、わたくし（サイト管理人moriy）ひとりが提唱しているもので、何ら学術的な裏付けはありません』

Answer (score 6):

先ず、確認しておきたいのは、「なんかってけっかる」とは、例え口語であっても通常は聞かれないフレーズであるという事実です。引用文中にあるように、興奮した人物が発したセンテンスであるということがポイントとなります。

こうした状況で発せられた言葉を、文法的、言語学的に分析するには限界がありますし、分析以前の問題として、読者たち自身もそこに「真面目な」な分析を求めているとは考えにくいと思われます。この作品は小説であり、語学の専門書ではないのです。

従って、作者はユーモアを交えた独自の「分析」をここで試みていると、個人的には考えます。「撥音便」、「リエゾン」といった専門用語を敢えて使用することにより、そのユーモアとしての効果を一段と高めていると捉えてみてはいかがでしょうか。

「撥音便」はフレーズ中に実際に使用されていますが、「リエゾン」と呼べるものが使用されているとは言い難いのが事実です。語感として重みのある両単語が、作者がここで目的とするユーモアに権威を与えているというのが、私個人の「真面目な分析」です。

Comment: 真面目なだけ、的を得ていますね（笑）そのとおり、ユーモアが作者の第一目標だったでしょう。